# Starting java with Dargs with a period from powershell

Tags: powershell

How to run this command which works on command prompt from powershell ?

`java -DSTOP.PORT=9100 -DSTOP.KEY=juststop -Xms256M -Xmx512M -jar start.jar`

It gives `Error: Could not find or load main class .PORT=9100`

I tried :

- `iex 'java -DSTOP.PORT=9100 -DSTOP.KEY=juststop -Xms256M -Xmx512M -jar start.jar'`
- `iex "java -DSTOP.PORT=9100 -DSTOP.KEY=juststop -Xms256M -Xmx512M -jar start.jar"`
- `@" same as above "@`
- Just `java -DSTOP.PORT=9100 -DSTOP.KEY=juststop -Xms256M -Xmx512M -jar start.jar` without iex
- And many more without results.

If you want to try things out just download apache solr and start and stop the jetty from powershell.

From command prompt the command to start is  `java -DSTOP.PORT=9100 -DSTOP.KEY=juststop -Xms256M -Xmx512M -jar start.jar` and command to stop is `java -DSTOP.PORT=9100 -DSTOP.KEY=juststop -jar start.jar --stop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running on PowerShell v3.0 try this:

```
java --% -DSTOP.PORT=9100 -DSTOP.KEY=juststop -Xms256M -Xmx512M -jar start.jar
```

If you're on V1 or V2 try:

```
java '-DSTOP.PORT=9100' '-DSTOP.KEY=juststop' -Xms256M -Xmx512M -jar start.jar
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the working answer. So is the "dot" in my command the reason for all my tries failing? - What made you put single quotes for a few args?

Comment: And what is the name of the --% operator? I cant do a web search without a name :( Google is taking me to random unrelated pages.

Comment: @Zasz I've not seen any official docs from Microsoft on this. I learned about it via MVP channels and blogged about it here: http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/powershell-v3-ctp2-provides-better-argument-passing-to-exes/

Comment: @Zasz It is also documented on the PowerShell team blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx