# Why can't I pass in system properties to elasticsearch on windows

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out how to pass system properties to elasticsearch when running on windows, but I can't see to get it right.

According to the documentation here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html you should for example be able to set the port number (this is what I'm using to try it out).

The command I try to execute is:

```
java -classpath ".\*;.\sigar\*" -Des.port=9201 org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap
```

With that I expect to get elasticsearch to run on port 9201, but instead I get: `Error: Could not find or load main class .port=9201`

So what I'm I doing wrong. It's not important that it is the port property, I just want to be able to set properties in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs for the java command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) specify that when being invoked with a class name, JVM options need to come first, then the class name, then any arguments:

```
java [ options ] class [ arguments ]
```

Your `-classpath` option is in the right place, but I think you need to move the `-Des.port` argument after the class name:

```
java -classpath ".\*;.\sigar\*" org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap -Des.port=9201
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that first with the -Des.path.data=C:\tmp\test property expecting to see the data folder to be located in c:\tmp\test, but that didn't do it so I thought something must be wrong. With the port property it works fine though. Thanks.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? Something incorrect, or something I can improve?

Comment: I really don't understand why you got downvoted, weird.

Comment: It did solve my problem, but I think the real problem was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924680/starting-java-with-dargs-with-a-period-from-powershell